# Detect iOS app moved to background without observers

Tags: ios, swift, animation, foregroundnotification

The app has an animation that stops when the app goes into background or foreground, and restarts when the app gets active again.

How can I do this without using observers? I read in other threads that this way is not a good practice and the app can crash.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myView.startAnimations()

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myView.startAnimations()
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myView.stopAnimations()
}

@objc func appMovedToBackground() {
    myView.stopAnimations()
}

@objc func appMovedToForeground() {
    myView.stopAnimations()
}

@objc func appBecomeActive() {
    myView.startAnimations()
}
```

(edited with the fix for "appMovedToForeground")

Comment: Why can it crash from this? Your code is fine other than mistakenly calling `appMovedToBackground` for the `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` event.

Comment: oh! thank you!  While I was looking for this solution I read that Apple advises to avoid this way and also that you have to remove the observer, which I don't understand very well what it means and if i need to do it here

Comment: There used to be a need to remove the observer but that isn't needed any more. See the documentation for `NotificationCenter removeObserver`.

Answer (score 0):

If you seek for stability and compatibility with older iOS versions, I would recommend KVObserver https://github.com/postmates/PMKVObserver, it helps maintaining the observer count, helping with the requirement to remove the observer when the observed object is going to be released for iOS 10 and below.

Your code is perfectly fine as it is, just fix the selector for UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5+**

I found a no proper solution & I don't suggest to use it but it works for me.

Put this function in to your main ViewController

```
 override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
 }
```

It calls when app is going to background.